# How to create a record in link with other object

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, object

I am new to apex triggers and starting new with trailhead i have this task to do :

Implement database trigger for Order object

● Trigger should create an invoice record for the order record always when a new

order record is created

● Newly created invoice record should be linked to the order record

● Link should be visible in the UI

I have already created a lookup relationship between order and invoice.

```
trigger createInvoiceRecord on Order (after insert) // After inserting a new order

{

for (order newOrder : trigger.new){ //for condition on the new order 

}

}
```

i believe this is a good place to start , just cant figure out a logic to connect the new order to the new invoice record.

Answer (score 1):

Records are related to one another using Ids. When you view a record in a web browser, Salesforce will display the *name* of the related record, but that's just something Salesforce does automatically as a convenience. The data stored in the relationship field is actually the record Id.

Another important point to consider is which SObject is the *parent*, and which is the *child*. A single relationship in Salesforce is always a one-to-many. The parent record can have many child records (and a child can only have one parent). There are ways to emulate one-to-one and many-to-many relationships, but that doesn't seem to be important to this question.

Based on what you've described so far, it sounds like `Order` is the parent, and `Invoice` is the child. That means that you need to take the Order Id (which isn't available in a `before insert` trigger context, but *is available* in an `after insert` context) and put it into the relationship field you created on `Invoice`, then insert your `Invoice` records.

That's pretty much all there is to it. You'll probably want to set a few other fields on the `Invoice` in addition to the relationship field, but that's generally a non-issue.

A quick and dirty example

```java
// DML and queries inside of loops are problematic (unless you really know what
//   you're doing).
// To avoid that, we use collections (lists, maps, and sets) to gather data inside
//   of a loop, and then perform operations on it outside of the loop
List<ChildObject__c> childRecordsToInsert = new List<ChildObject__c>();

for(ParentObject__c parent :trigger.new){
    ChildObject__c aChild = new ChildObject__c(
        // Use the parent's Id to set the relationship
        Parent_Relationship_Field__c = parent.Id,
        Some_Other_Field__c = 'some other value'
    );

    // You don't need to use the SObject constructor to set fields (but it does save 
    //   some typing)
    // You could instead set fields using dot notation (or even set some in
    //   the constructor, and some using dot notation)
    //ChildObject__c aChild = new ChildObject__c();
    //aChild.Parent_Relationship_Field__c = parent.Id;
    //aChild.Some_Other_Field__c = 'some other value';

    childRecordsToInsert.add(aChild);
}

// DML is OUTSIDE of all loops to help us comply with Salesforce's
//   various governor limits 
insert childRecordsToInsert;
```